# How can I do multiple ifs in the same event

Tags: java, if-statement, bukkit

I have this event here and i would like for it to check each if and execute each if. At the moment it executes like only 1 every once in a while. I would like it to go through every if statment and execute it regardless its true or not.

```
  int i = 0;    
      while(i < Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().length){if(Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()[i].getPlayer().getLocation().distance(loc) <= 55){//i only want others if statemet ran if this is true
        if(plugin.claymore.get(uui).equals(uui)){
                 Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()[i].getPlayer().sendMessage(p.getName() + "Mistakes were made");
                 plugin.claymore.remove(uui);
                 } 
           if(plugin.claymore.containsKey(uui)){    
                 UUID bozo = plugin.claymore.get(uui);      
                 Player jjg = Bukkit.getPlayer(bozo);
                 Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()[i].getPlayer().sendMessage(jjg.getName() + "'s claymore killed"+ p.getName());
                 jjg.giveExpLevels(50);  
                 plugin.claymore.remove(uui);          
                 }
                if(plugin.claymore.containsValue(Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()[i].getPlayer().getUniqueId())){
                 UUID bozzo = plugin.claymore.get(uui);      
                 Player jjhg = Bukkit.getPlayer(bozzo);
                 Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()[i].getPlayer().sendMessage(jjhg.getName() + "'s claymore killed"+ p.getName());
                 jjhg.giveExpLevels(50);  
                 plugin.claymore.remove(uui);      
                 } 
                 }                  
         else if(plugin.claymore.containsValue(Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()[i].getPlayer().getUniqueId())){
                 UUID bozo = plugin.claymore.get(uui);      
                 Player jjg = Bukkit.getPlayer(bozo);
                 Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()[i].getPlayer().sendMessage(jjg.getName() + "'s claymore killed"+ p.getName());
                 jjg.giveExpLevels(50);  
                 plugin.claymore.remove(uui);  
                 }           
                       i++;      
                     }
                   }
                 }
               }
```

once again I would like it to check every if statment and move on to the next regardless the if is true or not I want all the ifs ran.

Comment: Just remove the if statements if you want all your code to run.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run all if remove all `else`

```
  int i = 0;    
      while(i < Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().length){if(Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()[i].getPlayer().getLocation().distance(loc) <= 55){//i only want others if statemet ran if this is true
        if(plugin.claymore.get(uui).equals(uui)){
                 Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()[i].getPlayer().sendMessage(p.getName() + "Mistakes were made");
                 plugin.claymore.remove(uui);
                 } 
           if(plugin.claymore.containsKey(uui)){    
                 UUID bozo = plugin.claymore.get(uui);      
                 Player jjg = Bukkit.getPlayer(bozo);
                 Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()[i].getPlayer().sendMessage(jjg.getName() + "'s claymore killed"+ p.getName());
                 jjg.giveExpLevels(50);  
                 plugin.claymore.remove(uui);          
                 }
                if(plugin.claymore.containsValue(Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()[i].getPlayer().getUniqueId())){
                 UUID bozzo = plugin.claymore.get(uui);      
                 Player jjhg = Bukkit.getPlayer(bozzo);
                 Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()[i].getPlayer().sendMessage(jjhg.getName() + "'s claymore killed"+ p.getName());
                 jjhg.giveExpLevels(50);  
                 plugin.claymore.remove(uui);      
                 } 
                 }                  
         if(plugin.claymore.containsValue(Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()[i].getPlayer().getUniqueId())){
                 UUID bozo = plugin.claymore.get(uui);      
                 Player jjg = Bukkit.getPlayer(bozo);
                 Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()[i].getPlayer().sendMessage(jjg.getName() + "'s claymore killed"+ p.getName());
                 jjg.giveExpLevels(50);  
                 plugin.claymore.remove(uui);  
                 }           
                       i++;      
                     }
                   }
                 }
               }
```

Comment: i'm sorry not sure exactly how to add that. whats the subcondition? could you implement that into the coe i have. cause im pretty sure i already have it set up like that

Comment: its not working, it only does th efirst if statement sometimes

Comment: that may be cos all your code dependes on `if(Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()[i].getPlayer().getLocation().distance(loc) <= 55)` condition. So sometimes it might be true sometime false